# Magento - Ultimo - Theming Per Product

Tags: magento, themes, e-commerce

Using Ultimo, I'm trying to use the all the demos that are on the site on different products. For instance. For Computers, I want to use demo 1, for Cables I want to use demo 2. And so on.

All the products are on the same site.

Is there a way to customize this?

Comment: Ask the author of the theme?

Comment: apparently, its not a part of the theme. this should be done in magento itself. just not sure how to do it.